# Application for managing arrays of windows services

Tags: windows, windows-service

I have a situation where I need to manage a set of windows services across 50-75 computers.

I want to be able to see which of the services are running across them and to be able to turn them off and on from one central location.

I realize I can script a lot of that with PS but I was interested if there was a OSS or commercial product that I could use instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but System Center Operations Manager can be configured do what you need.  You can create a custom monitor that will read the state of a windows service that you specify.  You can also turn a service on and off.  I have done this with for our ColdFusion servers since there is (or at least not at the time) management pack for CF.  SCOM is a bit expensive and has a large learning curve though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add each server to Server Manager (Remote Administration Toolkit) and it will allow you to connect to that server and start/stop services